# Java copying one file into another

Tags: java

My code does what I want and it copies a file that is specified but, I only have it setup where it only copies the files within the code that are specified. I want it to take input from the user who gives a two file names and it copies one file into the other. I want to be able to copy any files that the end user gives it. I have now where it only copies these two files; the `report.txt` and the `report.sav`

```
fr = new FileReader("report.txt");
fw = new FileWriter("report.sav");
```

The end user may want to copy files outside of the given ones, how can I do this?

Here's my code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class CopyFile {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        FileReader fr = null;
        FileWriter fw = null;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader("report.txt");
            fw = new FileWriter("report.sav");
            int c = fr.read();
            while(c!=-1) {
                fw.write(c);
                c = fr.read();
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            close(fr);
            close(fw);
        }
    }
    public static void close(Closeable stream) {
        try {
            if (stream != null) {
                stream.close();
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [command line arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html)

Comment: Beside using command line arguments you might want to have a look to following shortcut `Files.copy(Paths.get(args[0]), Paths.get(args[1]), StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);`

Comment: I'm actually using the command line and notepad to write my code. Any links on `Files.copy(Paths.get(args[0]), Paths.get(args[1])`?

Comment: @Noah Check the Java Tutorials: [File I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) and [I/O from the Command Line](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way to achieve this is using `java.nio.file.Files` API with JDK 1.7 version. Get the source and destination file names from arguments of main method.

Sample code for file copy:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class FileCopy{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        if ( args.length < 2){
            System.out.println("Usage: java FileCopy <source> <destination>");
            return;
        }
        try{
             Files.copy(Paths.get(args[0]), Paths.get(args[1]),StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
         }catch(Exception err){
            err.printStackTrace();
         }

    }

}
```

Usage (example): `java FileCopy FileCopy.java FileCopy1.java`

Have a look at oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) for detailed list of Files API.

Comment: DUDE! you're a life saver! I made some random files and it copied each one! Simple and elegant code! I LOVE IT! Thanks again! :)

Comment: I want to further improve this answer. If destination already exists, it should overwrite instead of throwing exception.

Comment: Well yeah, it's suppose to print  `Usage: java CopyFile fromFile toFile`  error message for inappropriate number of input arguments

Comment: yes. Now modified copy API to overwrite destination

Comment: But I do see what you mean. It doesn't overwrite if the file already exists and throws an `FileAlreadyExistsException`

Comment: Files.copy(Paths.get(args[0]), Paths.get(args[1]),StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING) will do the trick. Check latest anwser

Comment: EXCELLENT! Thanks again! I will use this as a guide to finish up my program! :)